# Changes made in Sharepoint web interface to list aren't reflected when using REST method

Tags: powershell, rest

I've got a Sharepoint list to which I've added some columns, like so:

[image]

Now, I've been able to pull data from Sharepoint using the super awesome Rest API, using the below PowerShell code:

```
$Items = "https://$sharepointServer/$site/_api/web/lists(guid'$guid')/items"
Invoke-RestMethod $Items -Credential $creds |  select -ExpandProperty Content |
select -expand Properties | tee -va Computers
```

I've got the objects that I want too, here's a comparison of what I see in PowerShell vs. what I see for a similar object in SharePoint.

[image]

**Why am I missing properties?**

If you'll notice, I'm missing both Migration_Group and Location fields from the PowerShell request.  When I compare the output from both (and I'm using the same GUID here for the SharePoint REST request) I for some reason don't see these two added columns.  The columns were added after the initial list was created, if that is relevant.  Any thoughts as to why that might be?

---

**Update**

Vadim recommended I expressly request the fields I want, using a * search, like so:

```
https://$sharepointServer/$site/_api/web/lists(guid'$guid')/items?$select=*,Migr‌​ation_group,Location
```

Now, I see the columns!  But the column names are jacked up!  Any thoughts as to what I'm doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: Could you please provide the types of those fields?

Comment: Hi Vadim, these columns are Date and Time (migration_group) and Location (Single line of text).

Comment: I guess they are set to hidden, at least i cant see them in display form. Could you please try this query https://$sharepointServer/$site/_api/web/lists(guid'$guid')/items?$select=*,Migration_group,Location instead of https://$sharepointServer/$site/_api/web/lists(guid'$guid')/items .The idea is to request them explicitly

Comment: Using your method, I now see the columns in my PowerShell search, however, the column name is garbled.

Comment: Hi Vadim, I updated my post to show you what's going on.

Comment: The only explanation of this behavior that comes to my mind that those columns has been created via UI by specifying non English characters for names, no?